# iOS端末の端末解像度取得方法

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

http://www.dorapro.co.jp/engineerblog/?p=255

に載ってる、 iPhone6 Plus / iPhone6s Plus 5.5 inch 1920 x 1080    16:9

画面解像度を端末情報としてSwiftで取得したいのですが、どうも取り方がわかりません。

教えて下さいよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

iPhone 6 Plusで1080x1920の値が返ってくるのは`UIScreen.nativeBounds`プロパティですね。

```
print(UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds)
```

上記をiPhone 6 Plusのデバイスで実行すると、

```
(0.0, 0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0)
```

が返ってきます。

Answer (score 0):

一応下記の処理で解像度(2208.0 ✕　1242.0)は取得できますが、iPhone6 Plusだけ少し特殊なようで1920 x 1080の値は取得できないようです。

```
let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
let result = CGSizeMake(size.width * scale, size.height * scale)

print(result.height) // 2208.0
print(result.width)  // 1242.0
```

↓参考URL
http://qiita.com/YukiAsu/items/78a5bed63c12660e8024